My intention: the crosshair comes out when the button is clicked
I made some codes but didn't work as I intend.
Crosshair comes out unless I don't click the button.
My intention is that when the button (OnBnClickedCheck1) is pressed, the cross hair will come out.
My code is :
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BaslerCode.h"
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"
#include "CImageEventHandler.h" 
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>

void BaslerCode::OnImageGrabbed(CInstantCamera& camera, const CGrabResultPtr& grabResult)
{
    ptrGrabResult = grabResult;


    if (ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded())
    { 
        int Width = ptrGrabResult->GetWidth();
        int Height = ptrGrabResult->GetHeight();
    
        pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = Width;
        pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = -Height;

        SetStretchBltMode(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(),HALFTONE);

        StretchDIBits(m_pDC->GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, m_rectWidth, m_rectHeight, 0, 0, Width, Height, ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer(), pBitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);

        CWnd* pPictureBox = AfxGetApp()->GetMainWnd()->GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTUREBOX);
        if (pPictureBox)
        {
        CRect rect;
        pPictureBox->GetClientRect(&rect);
        //GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTUREBOX)->GetClientRect(&rect);

        int rectWidth = rect.Width();
        int rectHeight = rect.Height();

        if (bool OnBnClickedCheck1 = true)
        {
        CPen whitePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 255, 255)); 
        CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&whitePen); 

        dc.MoveTo(0, rectHeight / 2); 
        dc.LineTo(rectWidth, rectHeight / 2);

        dc.MoveTo(rectWidth / 2, 0); 
        dc.LineTo(rectWidth / 2, rectHeight);
        dc.SelectObject(pOldPen);}
        }
    }
}

Please forgive me if I did basic mistake.

This is a mistake if (bool OnBnClickedCheck1 = true) because this is a variable which is always true, so you always see the crosshair.

OnBnClickedCheck1 sounds like a callback which you are supposed to override. That callback should set a member variable to indicate that the button has been clicked, and that is the variable you should use in the if statement above.

In this question you showed some code which responded to a button click void Cimageviewer12Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonLive(). Now you have to do something similar for this new button.

@john I see. Thank you.
